# How to link buttons in android to perform a function?

Tags: java, android, xml

The Android code consists of two parts Java and the XML. The XML code has helped display the buttons and switches, what code to write so as to get an output of On and Off from it.

Comment: Please provide your code (Java and XML) by editing your question and clarify your specific question/problem.

Comment: I suggest you go through couple of tutorials to get the idea: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of basic code that allows a user to access the camera once a button has been pushed in an app:

```
 Button camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                  }
               });
```

*button1* corresponds to the android id for button in the xml script. You can then use the object that you've set the button to to set the *OnClickListener*. Inside of the the *camera.setOnclickListener* brackets is what you want to happen once the button is clicked. *Public void onClick* is a function that tells android to do something. I tried to put this in basic terms. If you'd like more specifics, there's really good android studio tutorial videos out there. This one is my favorite:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAbQgLGKd3Y&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
 }
}
```

or

```
<Button
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/self_destruct"
 android:onClick="selfDestruct" />

public void selfDestruct(View view) {
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question you are asking how to react to user click on a button or a switch.. 
if so, you should create an instance of `OnClickListener` and implement the `onClick()` method..

simple example:

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.btn_id);
b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
            }
        });
```